# Sql Server Mgmt Studio Msg: 'lock request time out period exceeded' when click on tables folder

Tags: sql-server, session

After logging into my DB this morning from my client SQL Server Express version

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      10.0.1600.22 ((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414 )
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     8.0.7601.17514
Microsoft .NET Framework                        2.0.50727.5485
Operating System                        6.1.7601
```

I clicked on the tables folder and got the warning message:

> lock request time out period exceeded

After a bit of googling the problem I decided to run sp_who2 and see what sessions were running. I then discovered a select into statement running with a last batch date of 01/05 08:56:14 and host name = my pc name. Not that I understand exactly what this all means but I do know that I have not ran any select into statements recently as have been off over xmas and new year.

So questions are:

1) Why is this running
2) What caused it to start running

Many thanks for help

Andrew

Comment: Obtain and run sp_whoisactive to see the statement that's running.

Comment: You probably have an uncommitted transaction.

Comment: @usr where do I obtain that stored proc whoisactive from?

Comment: From Google... It's by Adam Mechanic.

Answer (score 0):

the select into stmt coming from your PC is the result of sp_who2.  the lock request timeout while trying to open the tables was most likely a result of a dml operation.  If you still have the default trace files (assuming sql 2005 onwards) there will be an entry representing schema change operation at around that time